# jQuery toggle() with dynamic div ID's

Tags: jquery, wordpress, dynamic, toggle

I need some help with some dynamic jQuery - if thats what it would be called.  Basically, I have a number of DIVs, each with the same name, except an increasing number is added on the end - for example:

```
<div id="category-1"></div>
<div id="category-2"></div>
<div id="category-3"></div>
```

....so and and so forth.  On the main menu, I want to create buttons that toggle each item, so there would be a button to toggle category-1, category-2, and so forth.

The ability to add/remove categories is going to be part of a CMS (wordpress), so the jQuery needs to somehow count how many "category-" there are on the page, and then create a button for each one in the main menu.

I know how to create a toggle button in jQuery, however I have had no luck getting the dynamic-ness that I need (if thats even a word!).   My first and only attempt so far has been to use inline jQuery encased in PHP tags, so that a jQuery toggle button is  generated for each category DIV - it seemed to generate the code correctly when I viewed source, but the buttons didn't work, probably because PHP is server side and jQuery is client side. (thats just a guess).

Does anyone know how I create the jQuery code I need?

Thanks
Zach

Comment: So let me ask to clarify.  You have a number of div's already on the page.  And you want jQuery to generate a button for each div?  And this button, when clicked, will do something to the div that it's associated with?

Comment: Oh, and I think dynamicness should be a word... or maybe dynamicity or dynacrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the best way I could come up with:

```
var divs = $('div[id^="category-"]');
var num = divs.length;

for (i=1; i<=num; i++) {
    $('<button class="toggles" />')
        .text('Toggle div ' + i)
        .appendTo('#divToAddButtonsTo');
}

$('.toggles').live('click',
                   function(){
                       var thisIs = $(this).index();
                       $('div[id^="category-"]').eq(thisIs).toggle();
                   });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M3kEQ/).

Obviously this is run inside the `$(document).ready()`.

References:

- [attribute-starts-with `^=` selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/).
- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: @Martijn: I always like to link to the docs, because that way if something isn't quite right there's some clues as to what's going on under the jQuery abstractions; and thank you kindly! :)

Comment: I like this option the best, but I just need to figure out how to have the text as the category name (I would pull the category name from the CMS using PHP).  I'll try and do this myself but if you have any thoughts, please let me know :)

Comment: Ahhh Figured it out - I passed the category name into "name=" on the DIV, then tweaked the jQuery to use the "name" as the text on the button :-)

Comment: why `.live()` instead of a normal `.click()` ?  The elements are already in the DOM and listening for later additions to the DOM is unnecessary.

Comment: @Alnitak: because the buttons are added dynamically, so (as far as I know) the click event wouldn't be bound to them *without* using `live()`. I'm happy to be proven wrong, though (it'd be something new to learn, which would be good) :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're wrong.  See http://api.jquery.com/live/  .live() binds handlers to elements that don't exist _yet_.

Comment: @Alnitak, you're absolutely correct: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M3kEQ/1/). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Give your `div` elements a common `class` attribute, which you can then use in a single jQuery selector to find all of them in one go, e.g.

```
$('.cat').each(function() {       // for each element with class "cat"
    $('<button>')                 // create a button
    .text($(this).attr('name'))   // whose text is the cat element's "name" attribute
    .click((function(div) {       // with a click handler
        return function() {
            $(div).toggle();      // that toggles 'div'
        }
    })(this)                      // which is bound to 'this'
    .appendTo('#container');      // and the button added to a container
});
```

Working example at http://jsfiddle.net/ax2UR/1/

Note the use of the automatically invoked anonymous function in the click handler which is necessary to create a locally scoped copy of 'this' to represent the div that's being iterated over in the `.each()` loop.

EDIT - modified to follow the OP's mark up where he's used `<div name="...">` to pass the label for each div's toggle button.

Comment: But then they would ALL toggle on/off at the same time, when I want each one should toggle individually....

Comment: no, the selector will indeeed return all of them, but you could (for example) use `.each()` to register their own specific event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Start with getting the category ids, so we can build buttons accordingly (If you're building buttons on the server side, just ignore the first step, and do it on the server side instead.)

So we'll give the category divs a class like this

```
<div id="category-1" class="category-class"></div>
```

Then each over the divs to get their id stored in an array

```
var categories = [];
$(".category-class").each(function(i) {
     categories[i] = $(this).attr("id").replace("category-", "");
});
```

Now that we have all the category ids and we know how many they are, let's create the buttons dynamically

```
$.each(categories, function(i) {

  // append buttons with the same id number as the category divs
  $("#someDiv").append("<a id='button_"+categories[i]+"' href='/something' class='toggle-button'>button "+i+"</a>");

});


$(".toggle-button").live("click", function (event) {
      //prevent propagation
      event.preventDefault();

      // get the matching id
      var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("button_", "");

      // toggle the div with the same id as the button 
      $("#category-"+id").toggle();
});
```

I haven't tried the code, so I don't know if the syntax is 100% right, but you get the point I hope!

We just each over the category divs which now has a class, we'll fetch the ids in an array. Now we build the buttons accordingly to the category divs, with a matching id.

Then we create a live handler for the click event, so when someone clicks a button, we'll fetch the id from it, which matches with a category div, and we'll toggle the div with the matching id.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly count the number of item which has names that includes "category".  Then you create a button for each of them.
the code for finding all elements with id like category is something like:
`$(div[id='category']); //starts with`

You can look up the pattern of JQuery if you are interested in more complex patterns.

Comment: Would I need to manually create the code for each button?  It needs to be dynamic as categories may be added or removed via the CMS quite regularly....

Comment: You can add the buttons programmatically. When you have selected all the "category" div's.  You can add a button.  Something like: .each(function() {$("id-of-element-to-add-to").add("a"); }).  Not sure it compiles, but close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can create a corresponding button for each div on the server side:

1. Create a button for each div on the server side with a rel attribute that contains the id for the corresponding button. i.e.

`<input type="button" rel="1">`

So the rel attribute stores the corresponding div id.
 2. Loop through the buttons with .each and assign the click handler:

```
    $('.my_buttons').each(function () {
    $(this).click( function () {
        $('#category-' + $(this).attr('rel')).toggle();
    });
});
```

If you for some reason can't generate the buttons on the server side (I can't think of a logical reason why you couldn't though), then simply loop through each div using .each and create a corresponding button with a click handler attached.

Edit: Here's [a JSFiddle that shows a working concept](http://jsfiddle.net/39raC/4/).

Comment: Hey Corey - could you give me more information on how this would work, perhaps demonstrate in a JS Fiddle?    I tried generating the buttons via PHP with each button having a "rel" that corrosponded to the category number, however the buttons didn't work at all.  Let me know.  Zach

Answer (score 0):

Create button for each

```
$('div[id^="category-"]').each(function(index,value){
$(this).after('<a href="#" id="toggle-"'+index+'>toggle</a>');
});
```

attach toogle event

```
$('a[id^="toggle-"]').live('click',function(){
$("#"+this.id.replace("toggle-","category-")).toggle();
});
```