# Put generated items into lists

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am still fairly new to Stackoverflow, so forgive me if I am doing this wrong.  This question pertains to another question I asked a couple of weeks ago, which was solved at [jQuery toggle() with dynamic div ID's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325598/jquery-toggle-with-dynamic-div-ids)

I recommend you check the link I posted, so you can know what I am talking about.

So I now have my list of items being generated, I have switched out the "button" code and replaced it so each generated item is a "li" - however, I now have a list of items in my menu that have no order to them.  I need to designate some items as top level items, and have other items as sub-items on a drop down menu.

I was thinking that I could perhaps tweak my classes so that when the buttons are generated, top level items have a class and sub-level items have a class, something along the lines of:

```
<div class="category-1-top-level-item">Main Item</div>
<div class="category-1-sub-item">Sub Item</div>
<div class="category-1-sub-item">Sub Item</div>

<div class="category-2-top-level-item">Main Item</div>
<div class="category-2-sub-item">Sub Item</div>
<div class="category-2-sub-item">Sub Item</div>
```

Then, perhaps, jQuery could be used to detect the top level item "category-1" and any sub items marked "category-1-sub-item" and then output a properly formatted list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Top Level Item
        <ul>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
            <li>Sub Item</li>
        <ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then, of course, that list could be styled with CSS to make a nice drop down menu for sub-items and such.

I don't know if this would work as a solution or not (if it does then great), but I have been struggling with the code needed to get this working properly.

If someone could help, it would be appreciated so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though verbose, this seems to do what you're after:

```
var topLevel = $('<ul />');
var subMenus = {};

function getId(el){
    return el.attr('class').split('-')[1];
}

$('div[class^="category-"][class$="-top-level-item"]').each(function(){
    var topLevelDiv = $(this);
    var id = getId(topLevelDiv);
    var subItems = $('<ul />');
    var li = $('<li />').text(topLevelDiv.text())
        .append(subItems).appendTo(topLevel);
    subMenus[id] = subItems;
});

$('div[class^="category-"][class$="-sub-item"]').each(function(){
    var subLevelDiv = $(this);
    var id = getId(subLevelDiv);
    var li = $('<li />').text(subLevelDiv.text())
        .appendTo(subMenus[id]);
});


topLevel.appendTo('body');
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kobi/UuaSA/